# Как сделать фиксированное расстояние между слайдами в слайдере?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, слайдер

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста. У меня на сайте имеется слайдер из 8 слайдов с бесконечной прокруткой. По умолчанию на экране отображается 4 слайда, дальше с помощью кнопок справа можно переключать по одному слайду. Расстояние между слайдами всегда неизменно 20 пикселей. Мне нужно чтобы права граница моего слайдера совпадала с границей моих кнопок переключения. Пробовал разными способами, в одном из них на разрешении 1920 на 1080 все хорошо, но на 4К мониторах опять не совпадает. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Скриншоты и куски кода приложил ниже. Спасибо заранее!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    prevArrow: ".project__buttons-prev",
    nextArrow: ".project__buttons-next",
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1600,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 980,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          adaptiveHeight: true,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 850,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
        },
      },

      {
        breakpoint: 375,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          adaptiveHeight: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

```css
.projects {
  height: 100vh;
  height: 100svh;
  max-width: 1560px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.projects__title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: var(--medium);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.slider {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1560px;
}

.slider img {
  height: auto;
}

.slide-desc {
  max-width: 365px;
  text-align: left;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.slide-desc h3,
p {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.slide-desc h3 {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.slide-desc p {
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}

.project__buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<section class="projects" id="projects">
  <h2 class="projects__title wow animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Projects</h2>
  <div class="slider wow animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527" alt="projects-picture-one" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Delivery of Automation Equipment</h3>
        <p>Year: 2015</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmenbashi Complex of oil refineries</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?" alt="projects-picture-two" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, Installation and Commissioning of Yoloten Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2016</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?0" alt="projects-picture-three" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>EPC project on Construction of Water Purification System</h3>
        <p>Year: 2017</p>
        <p>Customer: Municipality of Ashgabat</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?1" alt="projects-picture-four" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Chaloyuk Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2018</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?2" alt="projects-picture-five" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, Installation and Commissioning of Bagtyyarlyk-2 Fiscal Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2016</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?3" alt="projects-picture-six" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply of Electrical & Instruments spare parts for offshore</h3>
        <p>Year: 2018</p>
        <p>Customer: Petronas Charigali Turkmenistan Sdn. Bhd.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?4" alt="projects-picture-seven" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply of required spare parts for overhauling of various pumps</h3>
        <p>Year: 2021</p>
        <p>Customer: Lukoil Uzbekistan</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?5" alt="projects-picture-eight" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, installation and commissioning of custody transfer metering units</h3>
        <p>Year: 2022</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="project__buttons wow animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">
    <svg id="button1" class="project__buttons-prev" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" stroke="black" />
      <path d="M29 34L20 25L29 16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg id="button2" class="project__buttons-next" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" stroke="black" />
      <path d="M21 34L30 25L21 16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мужик, у тебя марджин справа на слайдах. Либо их убери, либо добавь кнопкам такой же марджин

```
.slick-slide {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Да, это правда. Но у меня марджин справа стоит для того чтобы задать расстояние между слайдами. Т.к на всех разрешениях это расстояние должно оставаться неизменно одинаковым, 20 пикселей. Только нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы на последнем слайде который отображается на экране, этот марджин не работал. Или придумать какой-то другой способ задать расстояние между слайдами. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Причем самое интересное, что на 1920 х1080 разрешениях этот самый крайний марджин исчезает, а на больших разрешениях вновь появляется

Comment: Я бы просто зсунул блоки со слайдами в отдельный блок и через флекс выставил. Там и gap можно добавить, оно и даст расстояние между блоками. Ну или как Говорил добавь тот же марджин кнопкам. Я не люблю марджины)

Comment: попробую через дополнительный блок и флексы, ну а насчет марджина кнопкам, почему-то на full hd разрешении у слайдера пропадает этот марджин, и кнопки получается на 20 пикселей двигаются внутрь блока

Comment: попробовал я сделать через дополнительный блок с флексами, в таком случае у меня не работает слайдер. Т.к slick не подуразумевает использование дополнительного блока обертки внтури

Comment: обоим кнопкам position: relative; right: 20px;

Comment: опять же на 4к мониторах хорошо, на full hd внутрь на 20 пикселей заходят кнопки

Comment: я вот смотрю на разных разрешениях и все хорошо, ничего не уезжает. .project__buttons{ position relevate; right: 20px;} добавил

Comment: я кажется понял в чем проблема. У меня на всем сайте стоит общий margin, вот такой: body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0 10.5% 0 10.5%;
} из-за этого кнопки и уходят внутрь. Что можно с этим сделать?